# Working with carouFredSel, fx: 'scroll', weird behavoir using "divs"

Tags: caroufredsel

I'm doing a slider with carouFredSel, but i have a weird behavior with fx: 'scroll' when the items are encapsulated in "divs", the scrolling of the images works badly. But if i use only "< img >" it works well.
Do you know why?
I need to use the div for my slides texts.
Take a look here http://kuralmedia.com/_outside/test-Slider/index.html
Thanks,

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `float:left` in the `.slide` class. That is all.
Here you can see the solution working: [Solution Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/3tAjr/1/)